# SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC application I'm adding CSS and JavaScript files in the following way:

```
@Script.AddCss("~/Content/css/style2.css", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddCss("~/Content/css/tipsy.css", siteWide: true)

@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Content/js/modernizr-2.5.3.js", siteWide: true)
@Script.AddJavaScript(localPath: "~/Content/js/jquery/jquery.datatables.js", siteWide: true)
```

And the output looks like the following:

```
@Script.OutputCss()
```

And almost the same for JavaScript:

```
@Script.OutputJavaScript()
```

Then the template engine combines all the files into AXD files and puts into the source of the page preserving the content-type.

This works fine in all browser but not in IE9. Sometimes the stylesheets are not being loaded and the following error message appears in the console:

```
SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch 
scripts.axd?type=Stylesheet&hash=74A0F67DE9D74AFCDAE1AA539EA11099
```

Besides of that, when you look into the Network tab, the AXD files are being loaded twice - 2 AXD files for the CSS and 2 AXD files for JavaScript. One of each file weights 0 bytes. This happens not always but only sometimes, too often though.

Could anybody help me with an advise on where the problem can be?

Thank you beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

As due to MIME type mismatch css was ignored in ie 9 and 10. The MIME type can be correct by utility called [FIle TypesMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) It is freeware created by NirSoft. It turned out that the MIME type of .css had been changed to text/plain, preventing ie from rendering my styles. using FileTypesMan to change it back to text/css fixed the problem.

1. Download FileTypesMan from the NirSoft site. Use the links near the bottom of the page to select the correct version for your operating system (there are different versions for 32-bit, 64-bit, and Windows 98/ME).
2. Unzip the files to a local folder, and double-click FileTypesMan.exe.
3. When FileTypesMan has finished listing all file types, scroll down in the top pane to find .css.
4. Double-click to edit the settings.
5. Change the value to text/css in the MIME Type field in the dialog box that opens.
6. Click OK. Job done. IE 10 should now behave itself (well, at least as far as rendering style sheets is concerned).

Comment: If anyone is still having this issue. Double check the css file exists and is not return 404 or 500. That program is amazing as well.

Comment: To fix viewing offline/local files, change the Content Type to text/css at the registry key here: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css

Answer (score -2):

In IE9, you need a text/CSS MIME type for cross-domain stylesheets when the origin page isn't in the trusted zone. When origin in trusted zone, it should work without the text/CSS MIME, which is probably why you encounter your problem only sometimes.

So make sure the ContentType declaration is present in your page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/css" %>
```

hope that was the issue.

Comment: Could you please clarify what page are you referring to? The CSS files are actually phisical .css files and are being built into an .axd file by the templating engine. In which page should I put that directive in that case? Besides of that, the CSS files are on the same server, so there's no cross-domain request.