# CSS not rendered in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer

CSS files not rendered in IE 9 and 10 but works good in compatibility mode.

I am the following error get "SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch" in IE 10 .

wherein i don't get a content-type in my response header!

Further this is on my local.

Any suggestions could be appreciated.

Comment: So fix whatever software is making the HTTP response so it includes a content-type header.

Answer (score 1):

It has an answer, summary would be:

As due to MIME type mismatch css was ignored in IE 9 and 10. The MIME type can be correct by utility called [File TypesMan](http://nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) It is freeware created by NirSoft. It turned out that the MIME type of .css had been changed to text/plain, preventing IE from rendering my styles. using FileTypesMan to change it back to text/css fixed the problem.

1. Download FileTypesMan from the NirSoft site. Use the links near the bottom of the page to select the correct version for your operating system (there are different versions for 32-bit, 64-bit, and Windows 98/ME).
2. Unzip the files to a local folder, and double-click FileTypesMan.exe.
3. When FileTypesMan has finished listing all file types, scroll down in the top pane to find .css.
4. Double-click to edit the settings.
5. Change the value to text/css in the MIME Type field in the dialog box that opens.
6. Click OK. Job done.

IE 10 should now behave itself (well, at least as far as rendering style sheets is concerned).

**Not my work:** Its not my own search, you can see this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791928/1762944

I hope this fixed you!

I was wondering that you are not writing `type="text/css"` but you said, that you are! So I found this the next helpfull article! It has the same issue as yours. **SEC7113: CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch**

I just did a simple Google search for the issue, and this was the first result! You should have searched for the issue.

Comment: File TypesMan ? is a software .No other way to work make this work?

Comment: Actually if you read my answer, you would have come to know that this software just changes `MIME` type from one to other depending on the browser. So you can try out another code like this: `<!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no_js ie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no_js logged_in ie9" id="logged_in" lang="US"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 10]><!--><html class="no_js logged_in" id="logged_in" lang=""><!--<![endif]-->` This will change the classes or css files when there is IE or when there is a non IE browser :) Good luc!

Comment: Sorry about that, try this code and change the css file for IE10!

Comment: This code would take care of the css file and other type. It works when the IE is lt (less then) or gt (greater then) 10 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the attribute type="text/css" in your  tag. Place your style tag in `<head>` section.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.I already defined type="text/css" for all the <link> that has stylesheets. Any further ideas please?

Comment: May I take a look to your webpage?

Comment: webpage is a combination of lot of html files in my local.so could not show you..If you want i can show the <link> and <meta> added.

Comment: yes show me the head section and the incipit of the style.css

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"/>
   <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
   <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>

Comment: <link href="/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the CSS file gets delivery with the correct "Content-Type" from the server. It must be "text/css". Use the developer console to determine the current type.
Potentially you need to adjust/create the MIME type mapping (e.g. for httpd).

hth

Comment: currently i am not connected to any server and testing in local machine. Is there anything like i should set the content-Type in css file?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem with an embedded micro-controller (not a lot of control over the server changing content type). Not sure if this applies but I found going into Settings->Compatibility View Settings and adding the IP (site) address the CSS was accepted and the page rendered properly.